# Expression/word for talking about a seemingly different subject for a while?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Let's say you give a presentation where you intent to talk about A, B and C. But before you get to talk about B you feel that since it's a subject in a field not everyone in the audience might be familiar with (or remember well) you have to give a short introduction/overview into the field first before really talking about the subject. In some cases it might even seem unexpected to the audience members which is why you might want to explicitly preface this part of your presentation.

Now how would you call this kind of interruption?

- A digression?
- A tangent?
- An excursus? (Which is what you might call it in German.)
- …

(While a single word would be nice a phrase would work as well.)

Comment: You may "digress for a moment", " open a short parenthesis", or "make an aside".

Comment: Nothing wrong with "digression".  And "tangent" is appropriate if you're never likely to return.  But, to "warn" the audience of a planned digression, something like "First, let me give you some background" is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

More possibilities in the spirit of *introduction* and *preface*:

*background*    "Let me provide some background."

*groundwork*   "Let's start with some groundwork."

*lemma*      "Lemma A will be used in the proof
                             of Theorem T." (mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might call that part of the speech an 'interlude', where 'interlude' is defined as

> 3. *transf.*
>      a. An interval in the course of some action or event; an intervening time or space of a different character or sort.

["interlude, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97950?rskey=jSOdPE&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed January 02, 2016).]

Or you could use 'interlude' with a descriptive adjective, whichever seems most appropriate to you. Here are some possibilities:

- rhetorical interlude
- transitional interlude
- introductory interlude
- explanatory interlude