# What is the name of the rhetorical device that describes an author's interruption into a narrative for literary effect?

Tags: terminology

I would like to know what the name of the rhetorical device is that describes a sudden authorial interruption, to achieve some literary effect, into a continuing narrative which s/he is providing.

The case which most concerns me comes from the "Conclusion" to Thoreau's Walden. While relating the story of "an artist in the city of Kouroo who was disposed to strive after perfection" who decided to craft the perfect walking staff, Thoreau writes; "By the time he had smoothed and polished the staff Kalpa was no longer the pole-star; and ere he had put on the ferrule and the head adorned with precious stones, Brahma had awoke and slumbered many times." This narrative then continues with "When the finishing stroke was put to his work, it suddenly expanded before the eyes of the astonished artist into the fairest of all the creations of Brahma." But between these two narrational sentences Thoreau inserts the sentence; "But why do I stay to mention these things?"

> - By the time he had smoothed and polished the staff Kalpa was no longer the pole-star; and ere he had put on the ferrule and the head
>   adorned with precious stones, Brahma had awoke and slumbered many
>   times. *But why do I stay to mention these things?* When the finishing
>   stroke was put to his work, it suddenly expanded before the eyes of
>   the astonished artist into the fairest of all the creations of Brahma.

[reformatted to show aside more clearly (italics mine; EA)]

Exactly why he does this is difficult to determine, but I would be satisfied simply to know the name of this fairly common rhetorical device. Thank you.

Comment: An _authorial aside_, perhaps? Seems old-fashioned, but then so are authors.

Comment: The entire book is first person narration. So, if he quotes a story and then uses an I in some sentence, that is in keeping with the book,

Comment: Try *authorial intrusion* or *narrative intrusion*.

Comment: If not otherwise in first person, isn't this the device of [breaking the fourth wall](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fourth_wall)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression/word for talking about a seemingly different subject for a while?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297126/expression-word-for-talking-about-a-seemingly-different-subject-for-a-while) I doubt we'll get more specific (than aside / parenthetical / digression) commonly used terms. It's a pragmatic marker, directed at ... who?  The narrator? His envisioned audience? Is it purposeful? ... The narrator resumes as if nothing has happened. It also references the material.

Comment: Rhetorical question, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to determine when text is written in the voice of the author or some narrator who is the author's creation. (It's been a while since I read Walden, and I don't remember that section.) However, a major interruption like that can be called a "[parenthesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesis)":

> 1a: an amplifying (see AMPLIFY sense 1) or explanatory word, phrase, or sentence inserted in a passage from which it is usually set off by punctuation
> // explained further in a *parenthesis*
>
> b: a remark or passage that departs from the theme of a discourse : DIGRESSION
> // The speaker inserted some often amusing *parentheses* during his speech.